# g++ how to check if it supports lambda functions?

Tags: compiler-construction, g++, c++11

So much talk about lambda functions... So I tried to write mine. :(. It did not work. Does g++ 4.3.2 support lambda functions? How to find out whether it supports a certain c++0x feature or not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at Apaches [C++0x Compiler Support](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) page or [GCCs C++0x pages](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html). Only GCC >= 4.5 supports lambda functions.

If you need to write something that optionally takes advantage of lambda support you could do so conditionally depending on the GCC version or [Boost.Configs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.macros_that_describe_c__0x_features_not_supported) `BOOST_NO_LAMBDAS`.